# How to solve 'undefined reference to symbol 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'?

Tags: ros, boost, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

follow:[Moving the gripper](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20gripper)

```
 Linking CXX executable ../bin/simple_gripper
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/simple_gripper.dir/src/lian_gripper.o: undefined reference to symbol 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/simple_gripper] Error 1
```

How to solve it ?
Thank you !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37575/how-to-solve-%27undefined-reference-to-symbol-%27vtable-for-boost::detail::thread_data_base%27-?/) by [li-an](https://answers.ros.org/users/2411/li-an/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-06-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This typically indicates that you haven't set up you CMakeLists.txt correctly.

You are missing the Boost-related directives, try adding `rosbuild_add_boost_directories()` and `rosbuild_link_boost()` to your CMakeLists.txt

It should look something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_version(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake

rosbuild_init()
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib) 

rosbuild_add_executable(simple_gripper src/simple_gripper.cpp)
rosbuild_link_boost(simple_gripper thread)
```

For more information on using the CMakeLists.txt file, check out the [rosbuild wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists).

There are also some good examples on the [examples page](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples).

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [timdixon777](https://answers.ros.org/users/4505/timdixon777/) on 2013-03-22**:
Several of my classmates and I all had problems with the tutorial and were able to solve them by adding the boost-related directories.  This should be added to the tutorial documentation.